# Issue on start-up with Hazelcast (CONCURRENT_MAP_PUT)

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have three nodes on different servers. It works fine, but sometimes on node restart it falls into an infinite cycle like this:

```
    INFO  03-04 19:51:32,851 (LoggerInstance.java:log:185)  -/10.0.0.107:61000 [dev] ======= -1: CONCURRENT_MAP_PUT ======== 
            thisAddress= Address[10.0.0.107:61000], target= Address[10.0.0.9:61000]
            targetMember= null, targetConn=Connection [/10.0.0.9:39345 -> Address[10.0.0.9:61000]] live=true, client=false, type=MEMBER, targetBlock=Block [129] owner=Address[10.0.0.9:61000] migrationAddress=null
            ProxyKey {name='t:campaignsClicks', key=null} Re-doing [20] times! c:__hz_Proxies : null
    INFO  03-04 19:51:37,862 (LoggerInstance.java:log:185)  -/10.0.0.107:61000 [dev] ======= -1: CONCURRENT_MAP_PUT ======== 
            thisAddress= Address[10.0.0.107:61000], target= Address[10.0.0.9:61000]
            targetMember= null, targetConn=Connection [/10.0.0.9:39345 -> Address[10.0.0.9:61000]] live=true, client=false, type=MEMBER, targetBlock=Block [129] owner=Address[10.0.0.9:61000] migrationAddress=null
            ProxyKey {name='t:campaignsClicks', key=null} Re-doing [30] times! c:__hz_Proxies : null
    INFO  03-04 19:51:42,870 (LoggerInstance.java:log:185)  -/10.0.0.107:61000 [dev] ======= -1: CONCURRENT_MAP_PUT ======== 
            thisAddress= Address[10.0.0.107:61000], target= Address[10.0.0.9:61000]
            targetMember= null, targetConn=Connection [/10.0.0.9:39345 -> Address[10.0.0.9:61000]] live=true, client=false, type=MEMBER, targetBlock=Block [129] owner=Address[10.0.0.9:61000] migrationAddress=null
... and so on infinetely
```

Restart doesn't help. Only disabling network in hazelcast.xml and restarting all three nodes. Does anybody know what is wrong?

The config file:

```
<hazelcast>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true">60000</port>
        <join>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <interface>10.0.0.107</interface>
                <hostname>10.0.0.3</hostname>
                <hostname>10.0.0.9</hostname>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>
</hazelcast>
```

Comment: Which Hazelcast version are you using? And do you see all 3 nodes joined to the cluster properly in the logs? This seems like an issue on 1.9 versions.

Comment: I encountered this on 1.8.* as well.
Currently yes - I'm using 1.9.4.8. OK, I'll try to upgrade. But upgrade 1.8 -> 1.9 didn't help. So I'm not really optimistic about this.

Comment: On 2.0, connection layer significantly changed and lots of issues have been fixed.

Comment: I'll try to upgrade. Hopefully, it helps. I'll let you know in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - upgrade to Hazelcast 2.0.0 seemed to solve the problem (it has not been appearing for about 30 days).